# Equivalence principle in geometrical terms

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, equivalence-principle

I am learning general relativity by myself. I wonder if the equivalence principle is simply equivalent to, in geometrical terms, the statement that a Lorentzian manifold is locally flat, which is a somewhat trivial result from the point of view from math.

Comment: If depends what you're specifically taking the be the equivalence principle, as it is a somewhat qualitative statement (that has many different precise formulations). E.g., the weak EP is essentially this, but the Einstein & strong EP add some extra content. Perhaps state your version of the principle explicitly?

Comment: The content of the WEP strongly depends on what you're assuming at the outset-- inferences generally have hypotheses, and yours haven't been stated. If you've already assumed gravity is described by geodesic motion in a Lorentzian manifold, then the weak equivalence principle is indeed built in, containing no new information. However, if you only assume that the universe is a smooth manifold (not necessarily endowed with a metric), one can use the weak equivalence principle together with special relativity to construct a metric and argue that gravity *must* be described by its geodesic motion.

Comment: @jawheele Can you elaborate your last statement? The WEP is valid also in the classical spacetime, in some form. How  can you  prove  the existence of a metric by it? At most, I think, one can prove that there is an affine connection whose geodesics (some of them) are the worldlines of free falling bodies.

Comment: @ValterMoretti One must also assume that dynamics locally reduce to special relativity. Sorry for the plug, but the argument is too long to contain in a comment, and I had a bit too much fun in writing my dissertation and fleshed out my own thoughts on this there, in the introduction (Section 1.2, in particular the second and fourth subheadings in 1.2.3). It is available at https://dukespace.lib.duke.edu/dspace/handle/10161/27731

Comment: The gist:
(i) WEP gives a family of curves, trajectories of gravity. Further, those passing through a given $p$ are nearly linear in the coordinates of a freefall observer (who follows one of the curves) through $p$.
(ii) SR limit implies that the coordinates of different observers through $p$ are related by Lorentz transformations to leading order.
(iii) That LTs preserve the ST interval yields a conserved inner product on $T_p M$, i.e. a consistent metric tensor at each point.
(iv) That this metric is diagonalized when freefall trajectories are nearly linear implies they're geodesics.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.

Answer (score 11):

The part of (weak) equivalence principle where it is stated that the gravitational field can be locally canceled  can be mathematically stated as follows in a spacetime $(M,g)$. The Levi-Civita connection coefficients of $g$ in $M$ will be henceforth indicated by $\Gamma^a_{bc}$.

Consider a *timelike geodesic segment* $\gamma= \gamma(t)$, where $t\in (a,b)$ is the proper time (I assume $c=1$), that is the story of a free falling observer in a given gravitational field.

It is possible to prove that, given $t_0\in (a,b)$, there is a coordinate system $x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3$ around a tube that includes a portion of $\gamma$ before and after $t_0$ such that:

- (i) the equation of $\gamma$ is $x^0(t)=t$, $x^1(t)=x^2(t)=x^3(t)=0$ in the said coordinates;
- (ii) $g_{ab}|_{\gamma}= \eta_{ab}$ (the Minkowski metric) in the considered portion of $\gamma$;
- (iii) $\Gamma^a_{bc}|_{\gamma}=0$ in the considered portion of $\gamma$.

These coordinates are said **normal Riemannian coordinates around $\gamma$**. This result is by no means trivial and relies on the notion of *exponential map*.

I stress that the validity of (iii) for *all* choices of $a,b,c$ needs the fact that $\gamma$ is a geodesic, i.e., a free falling motion (if the geodesic is timelike).

Consider   another timelike geodesic $\alpha= \alpha(\tau)$  crossing $\gamma$ at $\gamma(t_1)$ for $\tau=0$: *it is another free falling body  thrown by the observer $\gamma$ at time $t=t_1$.*

Let us describe the motion of this body in the Riemannian coordinates around $\gamma$.

Taylor's expansion of the equation $x^a=x^a(\tau)$ of $\alpha$ performed around $\tau=0$ (when $\alpha$ crosses $\gamma$ at $t=t_1$)  gives
$$x^a(\tau) = 0 + v^a \tau + \frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2x^a}{d\tau^2}|_{\tau=0}\tau^2 + O^a(\tau^3)\:,\tag{1}$$
where $v^a = \frac{dx^a}{d\tau}|_{\tau=0}$.

However, in view of the geodesic equation that is satisfied by $\alpha$,

$$\frac{d^2x^a}{d\tau^2}|_{\tau=0} = - \Gamma^a_{bc}|_{\alpha(0)}\frac{dx^b}{d\tau}|_{\tau=0}\frac{dx^c}{d\tau}|_{\tau=0}=0$$
because $\Gamma^a_{bc}|_{\alpha(\tau=0)} = \Gamma^a_{bc}|_{\gamma(t_1)}=0$ due to (iii).

As a matter of fact, (1) reads

$$x^a(\tau) =  v^a \tau  + O^a(\tau^3)\tag{2}$$

This is a *constant velocity motion in Cartesian coordinates*, up to terms of order $O(\tau^3)$ **instead of** $O(\tau^2)$:

*We have canceled the gravitational field for small enough times and small enough spaces around the coordinate (spatial) center of a free-falling system.*

**Construction of the normal coordinates**

Take a pseudo orthonormal basis $e_a \in T_{\gamma(t_0)}M$, $a=0,1,2,3$ such that $e_0= \dot{\gamma}(t_0)$ where $t$ is the proper time along the godesic $\gamma$. Let $\{e_a(t)\}_{a=0,1,2,3}$ be the basis of the tangent space at $\gamma(t)$ parallely transported by the one at $t=0$.

Consider the map, constructed out of the exponential map generated by the Levi-Civita connection,
$$f: A \ni (x^0=t,x^1,x^2,x^3) \mapsto \exp_{\gamma(t)} \left(\sum_{k=1}^3 x^ke_k(t)\right)\in M$$
where $A\subset \mathbb{R}^4$ is sufficiently small  open neighborhood of $(t_0,0,0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^4$.

It is possible to prove, by direct inspection, that $df(t_0,0,0,0) \neq 0$. Therefore $f$ defines a local diffeomorphism (taking $A$ smaller if necessary).

By construction, the curve $\gamma$ is locally represented by $x^0=t$ and $x^1=x^2=x^3=0$.

Direct inspection proves that, for $x^1=x^2=x^3=0$ and every $x^0=t$ in the considerd neighborhood, $g_{ab}=\eta_{ab}$ and $\Gamma_{ab}^c=0$.

Comment: In your f equation , there is a typo.  I think you meant $x^0=t$

Comment: Corrected, thank you  very much.